# PHP PDO Setting a Quantity on Variable After Event Has Finished

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

i'm working on a project where people meet with another people like a social web site. Works like : one people creates an event like in the facebook and writes the when will event happen, maximum spots for event and so on, and people attends them.

i have a `met_with` variable in my database where i show in user's profile, which is a variable that works like, for instance when someone creates an event of 30 spots, people attend the event but maybe only 15 people attend or 25 people and like that and when user attend that event, he meets with `fullfilled spots - 1` people.

But the problem that i'm facing is, i want to set the `met_with` variable after event happens, not after when user joins, i've made that `met_with` variable is equal to `maximum spot - 1` but as i said, its not guarenteed that event will have fulfill its maximum spots.

I don't want to run a file, to update members' `met_with` variable everyday, is it possible to write a function that only sets `met with` variable after event happens.

Here is what i've did :

```
// above of here, i query the db for the event, i make the $free_spots = $free_spots - 1 after user clicks attending, fetching and defining $max_spot, $free_spots exc. 

$met_with = $met_with + $max_spot - 1;
try{
$update_member_query = "UPDATE `members` SET  `met_with`=:met_with, `attended` = `attended` +1 WHERE     `id`=:userid";
$update_member_query_do = $db->prepare($update_member_query);
$update_member_query_do->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update_member_query_do->bindParam(':met_with', $met_with, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update_member_query_do->execute() or die(print_r($update_member_query_do->errorInfo(), true));
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
$log->logError($e." - ".basename(__FILE__));
}
```

Comment: Some white-space and punctuation might make the first section a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I get this right, but here is what I would do:

- Setup a daily cronjob to process all events that finished the day (the period between cronjobs) before;
- In that cronjob, loop over all events that finished the day before, count all participants and add the number of participants - 1 to every participant. And of course increase the participants `attended` count accordingly.

Bottom line: I would not update user information when the user does anything on the site, but schedule it to run daily / periodically.

Comment: yes jeroen, you got it right, thank you for your reply, ill try that